# NullPointerException void java.net.HttpURLConnection.disconnect()

Tags: nullpointerexception, titanium, httpclient, appcelerator

Google Play Bug Reports.

I saw this error:

> 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void java.net.HttpURLConnection.disconnect()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run'

How can I resolve this at appcelerator titanium ? I'm using titanium.

Comment: Hi Eren, any solution found for this issue?